# Android: TextEdit Event Before Keyboard

Tags: java, android, kotlin

What is the Android event that can listen on for a TextEdit after getting focus and before the soft keyboard is displayed? I need to capture some information about the screen before the soft keyboard is displayed when a user clicks on TextEdit.

I have not been able to find an event graph that shows the order of events for TextEdit component?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ViewTreeObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver) to know about changes in tree view

also use its `addOnGlobalLayoutListener`, [This](http://cennest.com/weblog/2017/05/getting-keyboard-events-in-android/) may help you

Comment: I will take a look at this sugestions